# jquery Toggling between two interface states

Tags: jquery

Need your help. I'm trying to create a page that has two UI states. want I want is a function that when called toggles between them?

hopefully that's clear enough for some guidance.

Thanks

```
function toggleUIChange () {
jquery stuff for inital state, {
jquery stuff for other state}
}
```

Comment: What do you mean by state, and toggle what?

Comment: Toggle between two sets of jquery type things I'll write( like hide these divs, show these divs etc)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

jquery has a method `.toggle()` that can be used for hiding and showing elements on the page. . . You can also use `.toggle()` with custom callback functions for animation or really, anything else. Look [here](http://api.jquery.com/toggle/)

Comment: I don't see how that has two blocks of code to toggle between?

Comment: but I need it in a seperate function. that I can call in a bind something like switchUI(); and then i Switch UI I need the toggler to work?

Comment: @AnApprentice: $('.toggleme').toggle(); will hide/show all divs with classname "toggleme" (depending on whether or not the divs are visible or hidden). You can specify a callback function with this also, which will use two different functions when the div is either hidden or made visible

Comment: @AnApprentice: $('.toggleme').toggle('1000', nameOfYourFunction); This will do the hide/show in 1 sec and then call "nameOfYourFunction".